# How do I make the Activity wait before it switches to the new layout based on an Intent?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-intent, android-animation

I want to carry out an `Animation` on a view in my layout XML when I click on a button. Then once this `Animation` has finished, then switch to the new `Activity`. The `Animation` takes 1.2 seconds to action fully but unfortunately the page is actually switching to the new layout file before the `Animation` actually manages to display on screen. Here is the code for my `OnClickListener` which includes both the `Animation` and the returning `Intent`:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_out_right);
                relativeLayout.startAnimation(animation);

                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            synchronized(this) {
                                wait(3000);
                            }
                        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {

                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();               
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately I can't get anything to work, even after adding in a new `Thread` to carry a `wait` for 3 seconds like above! Any ideas are welcome and I also don't mind whether I have to use threads or not.

EDIT - ANSWER: Thanks to Gennadii Saprykin's suggestion of using the `onAnimationEnd()` callback.

```
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_out_right);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            relativeLayout.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `onAnimationEnd` callback instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Your background thread doesn't make sense in this case because it waits for 3 seconds in background but you are finishing activity in UI thread.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_out_right);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            //...
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();               
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        relativeLayout.startAnimation(animation);           
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought that may be the issue that I was waiting a new Thread and not the UI Thread. Do you have an example of the onAnimationEnd() callback in use? It sounds like it is on the right lines but I'm not too sure how to implement it.

Comment: just call setAnimationListener on your animation object and implement onAnimationEnd callback. It will be called exactly when your animation ends.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much. I was not aware there was such a method! I have updated my question to show the final code that I wrote to get it working.